# Logstash nested object aggregation is not working

Tags: mysql, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash

I have 3 tables : user, post, comment are joined with left join. I'm trying to create a nested object (posts) for each user. I'm able to aggregate the posts object but i want also to aggregate the comments object inside each posts object  it gives me each comment in separated object while more than one comment are having the same post id, i want to combine all post comments in one array. This is my filter :

```
filter {
    mutate {
    rename => { 
    "post_id" => "[posts][post_id]" 
    "post_user" => "[posts][post_user]" 

    "comment_id" => "[posts][comments][comment_id]" 
    "comment_post" => "[posts][comments][comment_post]" 
    }
    }

aggregate {
  task_id => "%{user_id}"
  code => "
      map['posts'] ||= []
  "
  push_previous_map_as_event => true
}

aggregate {
  task_id => "%{[posts][post_id]}"
  code => "
    map['posts']['comments'] ||= []
  "
  push_previous_map_as_event => true
}
}
```

This is the result :

```
{
'user_id' : 2,
'name' : 'farah',
'posts' : 
[
{
'post_id' : 1,
'post_user' : 2,
'comments':
{
'comment_id' : 1,
'comment_post':1
}
},
{
'post_id' : 1,
'post_user' : 2,
'comments':
{
'comment_id' : 2,
'comment_post':1
}
},
'post_id' : 3,
'post_user' : 2,
}
]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? What is happening?

Comment: The comments aggregation is not working..I got all users and in every user i got its posts. But when I'm trying to combine all comments for each post in one array. It's not working it gives me each comment in seperated object while more than one comment are having the same post id